# Xpath expression to skip root and get field value

Tags: java, xml, xpath

In my Java application, I process messages of `request` and `confirmed` of a queue. The fields which I map to my Java object model are identical in both messages. For example:

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<request>
    <trade id = "XXX">
        <tradeHeader>
            ...
            <tradeDate>2019-09-20</tradeDate>
        </tradeHeader>
        <repo>
            ...
            <bond id="ISIN">
                <instrumentId>
                    GB00BXXX
                </instrumentId>
            </bond>
        </repo>
    </trade>
</request>
```

Confirmed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<confirmed>
    <trade id = "XXX">
        <tradeHeader>
            ...
            <tradeDate>2019-09-20</tradeDate>
        </tradeHeader>
        <repo>
            ...
            <bond id="ISIN">
                <instrumentId>
                    GB00BXXX
                </instrumentId>
            </bond>
        </repo>
    </trade>
</confirmed>
```

For each fields which I am interested in, I have implementations which provide the `XPath` expression to extract the data from XML. For example:

```
public class InstrumentIdParser extends SomeMessageMapper {

    private static final String ID_XPATH = ""; // This is where I need some help with :) 

    //Constructor

    @Override
    public JavaObjectModel parse(final String payload,
                                     final JavaObjectModel model) {
        final String id = parse(payload);

        return JavaObjectModel(model)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getExpression() {
        return ID_XPATH;
    }
}
```

I want to use the same mapper above for both `request` message processing and also `confirmed`. What would be the `XPath` expression that I would need to use to skip the root `request` and `confirmed` so it takes be to `<instrumentId>` value?

Comment: I think no need to skip we can use both at a time like `//(request|confirmed)/trade/repo/bond/instrumentId`

Answer (score 1):

```
//trade/repo/bond/instrumentId
```

or

```
//instrumentId
```